# Do Keycloak and its different adapters implement the Openid Connect Backchannel logout spec

Tags: openid-connect, keycloak, redhat-sso

Keycloak does support back channel logout, but is it compliant with the Openid Connect backchannel logout draft spec? https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenID Connect Back-Channel Logout was implemented in Keycloak 12.0, which [shipped in December 2020](https://www.keycloak.org/2020/12/keycloak-1200-released.html).

Earlier versions only implemented an alternative, proprietary mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

This is [Keycloak's Jira Issue](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-2940) regarding this topic. Go and vote for it!

After going over the spec and Keycloaks implementation I have to say that **it is NOT compliant with the spec**. As an example, this is the difference in the required logout token format that should be sent from the OP to the RP:

> 2.4.  Logout Token
>
> OPs send a JWT similar to an ID Token to RPs called a Logout Token to
>   request that they log out. ID Tokens are defined in Section 2 of
>   [OpenID.Core].
>
> The following Claims are used within the Logout Token:
>
> ```
> iss
>     REQUIRED. Issuer Identifier, as specified in Section 2 of [OpenID.Core]. 
> sub
>     OPTIONAL. Subject Identifier, as specified in Section 2 of [OpenID.Core]. 
> aud
>     REQUIRED. Audience(s), as specified in Section 2 of [OpenID.Core]. 
> iat
>     REQUIRED. Issued at time, as specified in Section 2 of [OpenID.Core]. 
> jti
>     REQUIRED. Unique identifier for the token, as specified in Section 9 of [OpenID.Core]. 
> events
>     REQUIRED. Claim whose value is a JSON object containing the member name http://schemas.openid.net/event/backchannel-logout. This declares that the JWT is a Logout Token. The corresponding member value MUST be a JSON object and SHOULD be the empty JSON object {}. 
> sid
>     OPTIONAL. Session ID - String identifier for a Session. This represents a Session of a User Agent or device for a logged-in End-User at an RP. Different sid values are used to identify distinct sessions at an OP. The sid value need only be unique in the context of a particular issuer. Its contents are opaque to the RP. Its syntax is the same as an OAuth 2.0 Client Identifier.
> ```
>
> A Logout Token MUST contain either a sub or a sid Claim, and MAY
>   contain both. If a sid Claim is not present, the intent is that all
>   sessions at the RP for the End-User identified by the iss and sub
>   Claims be logged out.

And this is what Keycloak sends in its current version (8.0.1):

```
{
  "id": "3536c4c4-fa51-4691-bc09-d229df83f774-1579360301277",
  "expiration": 1579360331,
  "resource": "resource-server-1",
  "action": "LOGOUT",
  "adapterSessionIds": [
    "6569208C4937FD9C6E138C9DD9CF7C6F"
  ],
  "notBefore": 0,
  "keycloakSessionIds": [
    "ca8060fd-48e9-4d26-b2d6-d6edb095f4b7"
  ]
}
```